# Overriding versus function pointers

Tags: function, overriding, function-pointers

Why do programmers prefer overriding to using function pointer fields?

Performance benefits? - Not that I know of.
Is it code readability? - No, the syntax is pretty much the same.

The only difference I see is a contra, and that is, function pointers can be changed at runtime.
What am I missing here?

Comment: "The syntax is pretty much the same"? Which language are you working in?

Comment: @larsmans What I meant is you can call them the same way. Declaration syntax is of course different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is not the same, not even the calling syntax. If you look at a C library such as [Berkeley DB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/) that uses function pointers, you'll see that you have to call functions like

```
db->fd(db, &filedesc);
```

I.e. `db` has to be repeated to get what is in C++ known as `this` (an implicit argument to every non-static method).

And, as you admit, the declaration syntax is different, as is setting up the structs/classes. With function pointers, you'd need to set the function pointers yourself on every instance. That's tedious and error-prone.

Apart from that, overriding is safer because it avoids issues where function pointers are null or are reset to point to funny places.

Answer (score 0):

You can write flexible functions and libraries that allow the programmer to choose behavior by passing function pointers as arguments.